# Pandas expanding count of string occurrence by group

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create an expanding count, by group, of the occurrence of a tuple of strings.

```
   index    category           group
2000-01-01  ('foo',)             a
2000-01-02  ('tito', 'puente')   a
2000-01-03  ('bar',)             a
2000-01-04  ('zip',)             b
2000-01-05  ('zorp',)            b
2000-01-03  ('feep',)            c
```

Would become:

```
   index    category           group   tuple_count
2000-01-01  ('foo',)             a        0
2000-01-02  ('tito', 'puente')   a        1
2000-01-03  ('bar',)             a        2
2000-01-04  ('zip',)             b        0
2000-01-05  ('zorp',)            b        0
2000-01-03  ('feep',)            c        1
```

The idea is that I want to create an expanding window, by group of the counts of the occurrence of categories that I'm interested in. In this case, the interesting categories are `[('tito', 'puente'), ('bar',), ('feep',)]`. As a new category appears, i want to add to the count.

I'm using the following code and can't figure out why it isn't working

```
from operator import or_

def count_categories(ser):

    categories_to_count = [('tito', 'puente'),
                           ('bar',),
                           ('feep',)]

    conditions = [ser == val for val in categories_to_count]
    mask = reduce(or_, conditions)
    return mask.sum()


def expanding_count_categories(s):
    return s.expanding().apply(count_categories)

df.groupby('group')['category'].apply(expanding_count_categories)
```

For the tuple_count column, I just get the category column back:

```
index              tuple_count
2000-01-01         ('foo',)
2000-01-02         ('tito', 'puente')
2000-01-03         ('bar',)
2000-01-04         ('zip',)
2000-01-05         ('zorp',)
2000-01-03         ('feep',)
```

edit:

Issue seems to be that non-numerics are currently [not handled by expanding/window](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/12541)

Comment: I cannot understand the logic of that tuple_count. Why are the b's zero and first c one?

Comment: `count_categories` only counts appearance of the tuples in `categories_to_count`. `b` categories are not in that list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since non-numerics are currently not handled by windows, it's seems like the best way to do this is to create a dummy first and then do a running sum on that. This has the advantage of also working on rolling windows as well.

```
categories_to_count = [('tito', 'puente'),
                       ('bar',),
                       ('feep',)]

df['has_category'] = np.where(X['category'].isin(categories_to_count), 1, 0)

df.groupby('group')['has_category'].apply(lambda x: x.expanding().sum())
```

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure about your expanding approach, but consider using `rank()` in a groupby apply function, ordering by dates within the group and checking categories with `isin()`. The only caveat is not having a column named *index* which conflicts with *index* in groupby series which does not have a rank attribute. Should you need to, consider setting and renaming index after the tuple count operation:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'datesix':['2000-01-01', '2000-01-02', '2000-01-03',
                             '2000-01-04', '2000-01-05', '2000-01-06'],
                   'category':[('foo',), ('tito', 'puente'), ('bar',),
                               ('zip',), ('zorp',), ('feep',)],                   
                   'group': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c']})

df['datesix'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datesix'])

def count_categories(ser):
    categories_to_count = [('tito', 'puente'),
                           ('bar',),
                           ('feep',)]

    ser['tuple_count'] = ser.datesix[(ser.category.isin(categories_to_count))].rank()
    ser['tuple_count'] = ser['tuple_count'].fillna(0).astype(int)
    return ser

df = df.groupby('group').apply(count_categories)

#          category     datesix group  tuple_count
# 0          (foo,)  2000-01-01     a            0
# 1  (tito, puente)  2000-01-02     a            1
# 2          (bar,)  2000-01-03     a            2
# 3          (zip,)  2000-01-04     b            0
# 4         (zorp,)  2000-01-05     b            0
# 5         (feep,)  2000-01-06     c            1
```

Comment: Wow. nice! I'm still trying to get my head around this. Why are you using `datesix` for the `rank` method. Could you use any column in `datesix` place so long as the dataframe is already ordered?

Comment: Unfortunately not, `rank()` ranks on specific variable. See it with category and item with most elements have larger outcome: 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1 for tuple_count.

Comment: Looked this over a bit more and it won't maintain the count from a previous row if the current row doesn't have a category of interest.